# Running multiple lldb processes in parallel

Tags: ios, xcode, parallel-processing, gdb, lldb

I am trying to execute an iOS app on multiple physical devices in parallel. In the past (XCode 4.3 and iOS 6) I accomplished that with fruitstrap, which used the gdb debugger (iOS 6.1.3 and lower). With XCode 5 Apple removed the [gdb debugger](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) and replaced it with the [lldb debugger](http://lldb.llvm.org/).

I refactored my fruitstrap script that it works with the lldb debugger. However, a execution of multiple lldb processes in parallel is not possible. I get the following error message in the lldb console:

```
(lldb) run
error: a process is already being debugged
```

I can see in the [apple source code}(http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-76/source/API/SBTarget.cpp) that they are allowing only one process at a time:

```
if (sb_process.IsValid())
    {
        state = sb_process->GetState();

        if (sb_process->IsAlive() && state != eStateConnected)
        {       
            if (state == eStateAttaching)
                error.SetErrorString ("process attach is in progress");
            else
                error.SetErrorString ("a process is already being debugged");
            sb_process.Clear();
            return sb_process;
        }            
    }
```

**Questions**

- Does anyone figures out how to run multiple lldb processes in parallel?
- Is there any other tool which can launch an iOS app on multiple physical devices in parallel, which is iOS 6 and iOS 7 compatible and can be executed via the command line? ([XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) works only for iOS 7, [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html) don't accept multiple processes in parallel, [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) used in the past gdb as well)?

Any help or thoughts appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

lldb only supports one process per target, but you can have any number of targets (using the same executable file or different files) concurrently.  From the command-line you can use "target create" to create new target (the "file" command is just an alias for  "target create"), "target list" to list them, "target select" to select the one you want, and then all the execution control and inspection commands work on the currently selected target.

For gdb you must have been running one gdb per process, since gdb doesn't support more than one process at a time.  You could also run multiple lldb's, thought that isn't necessary and the Targets will share any common debug information so running a bunch of target/processes in one lldb session is more efficient.

Note, if you are scripting this it may be easier to use the lldb Python API's.

Comment: Quick note: GDB does support multiple processes à-la fork and exec: see https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html and https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html (but only on Linux)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  It's been years since I worked on gdb, so my knowledge is a little stale at this point.  Is the architecture support for gdb still done at configure time, or can one gdb debug a heterogenous set of inferiors?